# Loading OpenGL extension at runtime

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

I am trying to acquire additional openGL functions e.g. glCreateShader(),
using wglGetProcAddress at runtime, as described in many tutorials.
The return value however is NULL and no shader-related functions can be 
found.

How can this problem be solved?
Thanks!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those functions are provided by the graphics driver. So you have 2 options:

- Upgrade your graphics driver to the latest version and hope that the manufacturer has developed that extensions.
- Change your graphics card to a better one, which driver provides the required extensions.

Note that there are many of low-end graphics cards that simply cannot do what that extensions require, so their manufacturers will never provide them.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem.
The openGL context must be created first, and the pixel format must be selected
and suitable for the set of extensions you want.

If you do not do the above, wglGetProcAddress will not find your extensions.

Comment: Well, if you'd have read the documentation of `wglGetProcAddress` you'd known that from the beginning. People, really, Read The Fine Manuals (RTFM)

Comment: As a matter of fact I did a lot of RTFM, this specific fact was not documented anywhere and is only hinted by the MSDN documentation when they mentioned an already existing pixel format. Then I tried and got it to work. Please stop spending time telling people what would happen if they read the manual, as this brings no contribution

Comment: From the `wglGetProcAddress` reference page, the very first sentence: `<quote>` "The *wglGetProcAddress* function returns the address of an OpenGL extension function for use with the **current** OpenGL rendering context." `</quote>` – I think it's pretty clear that to have a *current* context you first must create one and make it active.